# How to generate a table for each value of the HiddenField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I am developing a web application that has a huge database. I have the following tables in my database:

> Group Table: GroupID, GroupName
>
> Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID
>
> User Table: Username, Name, Job
>
> User_Course Table: Username, CourseID

The first attribute is the primary key in each table except for the last table.

Now, I am trying to create a table for each type of courses based on the value of GroupID. I have three groups of courses. I am using a PlaceHolder that I am using it to the HtmlTable. I used this method for flexibility because I have many complicated things which can't be done by the other controls like GridView and so no.

Anyway, I could be able to create the table and everything works well and fine. Now, I want to generate a table for each group of course based on the value of GroupID which is the HiddenField.

My code:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />    
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="1" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport">    
    <SelectParameters>
        <%--ControlParameter is linked to the HiddenField above to generate different GridView based on different values of GroupID--%>
        <%--<asp:Parameter  Name="GroupID" DefaultValue="3" />--%>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="GroupID" PropertyName="Value" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Button ID="updateButton" runat="server" OnClick="updateButton_Click" Text="Update" />
```

and my code-Behind:

```
//create a new HtmlTable object
HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
int columns = dv.Table.Columns.Count;
int rows = dv.Count;

//table's formating-related properties
table.Border = 2;
table.CellPadding = 3;
table.CellSpacing = 3;

//to get the css style
table.Attributes["class"] = "mGrid";

//create a new HtmlTableRow and HtmlTableCell objects
HtmlTableRow row;
HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTableCell cell;

foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
{
    HtmlTableCell headerCell = new HtmlTableCell("th");
    headerCell.InnerText = column.Caption;
    header.Cells.Add(headerCell);
}
table.Rows.Add(header);

//loop for adding 5 rows to the table
foreach (DataRowView datarow in dv)
{
    row = new HtmlTableRow();
    row.BgColor = "yellow";

    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        cell = new HtmlTableCell();
        if (j < 4)
        {
            cell.InnerText = datarow[j].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
            
            int checkBoxColumns = dv.Table.Columns.Count - 5;
            string fieldvalue = datarow[j].ToString();
            string yes = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
            string courseid = fieldvalue.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
            checkbox.ID = row.Cells[3].InnerText + "," + courseid.Trim();
            checkbox.Checked = yes.Equals("Yes");
            cell.Controls.Add(checkbox);
        }

        //add the cell to the current row
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    //add the row to the table
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

//add the table to the page
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);
```

I know that the above code should be inside a loop, but I did not how to come up with this loop.

Comment: Do *not* post a question repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `SqlDataSource` result in code-behind, leave it for control-side databinding.

Use pure ADO.NET object instead: SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, e.g.:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;

    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = (int)reader["ID"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a new ASP.NET developer and I already got many concepts and I want to utilize them before going to other concepts. Could you please tell me how to use it with the SqlDataSource?

Comment: @User: Or better learn how to use `GridView` or `DetailsView`. They will build a data-bound table for you.